# I am enable to get the success message..!

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

i am trying to get the user details into database and data is stored..i want a success message to fade in i have tried out some code but sadly its not working...plzz help me out of this..beg u pardon if am wrong..
                    here gose my **register.php** code

```
               <?php
    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // json response array
    $response = array("error" => false);
    if (!empty($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['mobile'])){
        // receiving the post params
        $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mobile = trim($_POST['mobile']);

        // validate your email address
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // valid email address
            if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
                // user already existed
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // create a new user
                $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);
                if ($user) {
                    // user stored successfully
                    $response["error"] = false;
                    $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
                    $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
                    $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
                    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                    echo json_encode($response);
                } else {
                    // user failed to store
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // invalid email address
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["error_msg"] = "invalid email address";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

and here gose the **.html** file with jquery..

```
              <html>
    <head>
<title>jQuery Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "register.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

    <!--html body-->
    <form name = "register" id = "register" method = "POST">
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input type = text name = "fname" id = "fname" required>
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "lname" id = "lname" required>
        <label>E-mail:</label>
        <input type = "email" name = "email" id = "email" required>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password" required>
        <label>Mobile no:</label>
        <input type = "number" name = "mobile" id = "mobile" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="submit" id = "submit">
    </form>
    <div id = "result" align = "right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here gose me /*.js*/ file

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "register.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                fname: $("#fname").val(),
                lname: $("#lname").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                mobile: $("#mobile").val()
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (json) {
                $("#result").html(json.user.email);  // like that you can display anything inside #result div
                $("#result").fadeOut(1500);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: why do you have an `href = "#"` in an input?

Comment: sir..!! i have removed it but it had no effect over my output..!!:(

Comment: check for errors on PHP/SQL and check your console.

Comment: yes sir i did it..its having no problem..each and every function is working out fine..!!

Comment: even data is stored into data base..!!

Comment: then what is your problem ?

Comment: sir..!! i am unable to get the last success message from jquery ajax function..!!

Comment: whether your functionalities are  working fine?insert, check user etc

Comment: Why hiding your #result and then fadeIn? Use CSS to hide it, and use fadeIn to show it after the request

Comment: To make sure you get the response, use console.log(jsonStr)

Comment: tried it out sir..!! i think its not entering function..!!

Comment: Does it save the user into the database ?

Comment: yes...sir,user data is entered into database

Comment: @krishna Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve using `jsonStr` in `success`?

Comment: sir..!! i am juz trying to output a success message after the user details are successfully stored in database..!! if not an error message

Comment: @krishna So you don't want to display user's details in `#result` div?

Comment: It's strange you're saying that it saves the user but you don't get a success callback. Do you get any response in your `success` function if you add `echo "Register check";` below `$response = array("error" => false);`

Comment: @rajdeep sir..!! the thing is firstly i tried it but it dint work out..soo better i thought of at least displying succes..message..!!

Comment: @hakan sir..!! even i was..put in a thought but the truth is data is saved i.e ajax calls the url executes it and just doesn't gets back:(

Comment: @krishna see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `JSON.stringify(jsonStr)` because jQuery has **already** parsed the response object for you. jQuery will look at the `Content-Type` of the response and, if it's `application/json`, it will parse it, and provide the parsed result to your success handler.

Your jQuery should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "register.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                fname: $("#fname").val(),
                lname: $("#lname").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                mobile: $("#mobile").val()
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (json){
                if(json.error){
                    $("#result").html(json.error_msg);  // display error message
                }else{
                    $("#result").html(json.user.email);  // like that you can display anything inside #result div
                }
                $("#result").fadeOut(1500);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: sir..!! it seems that even empty feilds are taken in to database..i have used ||....!==") but is seems to be not working

Comment: @krishna You mean to say in `storeUser` method some empty fields are getting inserted into the `users` table, right?

Comment: sir...I have solved it sir...thanks for reply...but i am now facing problem wit email validation

Comment: i have updated it sir..!!now problem is email validation in it i want to use  filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) in this code but confused

Comment: i have asked a new question..!! plz help me out sir..!!@ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128372/how-efficently-may-i-use-filter-varemail-filter-validate-email

Comment: @krishna let me take a look at it.

Comment: @krishna Please see my answer there.

Comment: sir..the solution which u gave me for the question above is only working for success message..!! when ever their is an error as you specified its not giving a alert on error i.e textStatus..sir i have updated the whole question plz if you could assist me on this one..!!

Comment: @krishna `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ ... }` is called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides `null`) are `"timeout"`, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and `"parsererror"`. When an HTTP error occurs, `errorThrown` receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error".

Comment: soo sir..is their any way i could display alert on empty fields/say so invalid email in back-end side and display alert in front-end

Comment: @krishna I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code.

Comment: @krishna No, `error_msg` comes from your `register.php`. Look at these statements, `$response["error"] = true; $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";`. There's a key field `error_msg` in your `$response` array.

Comment: ur...superb sir...!! accurate..!!

Comment: sir..may i get your assistance on this question..!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197062/back-end-error-msg-is-not-giving-a-alert

Comment: no..sir i have to display out the error messages as you ansered in your previous...and on success message then perform action in form tag...if one happens other is not executing..e.preventDefault(); is not working out as its not stopping the page to move to login.html

Comment: @krishna So after displaying *Registeration successful!* you want to submit the form and redirect it to *login.html*, right?

Comment: exactly sir...i have tried out lots of hour resolving it..sadly not unable to do so..!!